# How to select data of all months of user selected year even its empty

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, posbila and posbilb.
The field `bill_date` (store with dateTime format) is in table posbila and field `Qty` in posbilb.

I have tried the follow query but the months with empty data wont be shown

```
SELECT
    posbilb.stkcode,
    SUM(posbilb.qty),
    date_format(posbila.bill_date, '%m/%y')

FROM
    posbila,posbilb
WHERE
    posbila.bill_no = posbilb.RECEIVE_ID

GROUP BY 
    1, 3
```

If user select year 2015 I want the following result:

> **Month     | Qty**
>   Janury    | 154
>   February  | 00
>   March     | 123
>   April     | 00
>   May       | 00
>   June      | 60
>   July      | 00
>   August    | 99
>   September | 00
>   October   | 00
>   November  | 10
>   December  | 00

Comment: If your tables really don't have the missing dates, then you may have to use a calendar table to include this missing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a dates table and don't have permission to create one you could us union. For example
given

```
select * from tbl_loanledger;
+------+-------------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------+---------+
| id   | borrower_id | loanmaster_id | payment | balance | date_created | deleted |
+------+-------------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------+---------+
|    1 |           4 |             1 |      50 |     250 | 2016-05-28   |       0 |
|    2 |           1 |             2 |      20 |      80 | 2016-05-25   |       0 |
|    3 |           1 |             2 |      30 |      50 | 2016-06-01   |       0 |
|    4 |           2 |             3 |     100 |     400 | 2016-06-09   |       0 |
|    5 |           2 |             3 |      50 |     350 | 2016-06-10   |       0 |
|    6 |           1 |             4 |      50 |     200 | 2016-06-16   |       0 |
|    7 |           1 |             7 |      50 |     250 | 2016-06-16   |       1 |
+------+-------------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------+--------+

set @yyyy = '2016';

select      date_format(s.date_created, '%m/%y') 'mm/yy', sum(s.payment) amount
from
(
select  1 as srce,ll.payment payment, ll.date_created date_created from tbl_loanledger ll
union select 2 ,0, concat(@yyyy,'-01-31') union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-02-01') union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-03-31')
union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-04-30') union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-05-31') union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-06-30')
union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-07-31') union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-07-31') union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-09-30')
union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-10-31') union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-09-30') union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-12-31') 
) s 
group       by 1
```

results in

```
+-------+--------+
| mm/yy | amount |
+-------+--------+
| 01/16 |      0 |
| 02/16 |      0 |
| 03/16 |      0 |
| 04/16 |      0 |
| 05/16 |     70 |
| 06/16 |    230 |
| 07/16 |      0 |
| 09/16 |      0 |
| 10/16 |      0 |
| 12/16 |      0 |
+-------+--------+
```

Comment: union select 2 ,0, concat(@yyyy,'-01-31') Can i know what is "2 ,0,"  stands for?

Comment: because i want to select 2 more column from another table and seem like it makes my query gone crazy

Comment: Union appends data from multiple select statements and requires each select statement has the same number and type of fields. The field names (and types in this case) are inherited from the first select so do not need to be restated in subsequent select statements. Out of habit I usually identify "real" data with a srce value of 1 and and "dummy" data with a different srce value (in this case 2) - because I might, for example, want to count only real data, The value 0 maps to the header payment.