# How to list records in a year, from Jan to Dec even its null

Tags: mysql

I am doing a report that let user to enter year and stock code. The report will show the monthly sales of an item from Jan to Dec of the selected year from user. The results must be all 12 months even if data not exist.

```
set @yyyy = 2016;

select date_format(bb.bill_date, '%m/%y') as date_1, sum(bb.Qty), stockcode
from
(
select  1 as srce, zz.qty Qty, zz.stkcode stockcode, ll.bill_date bill_date 
FROM posbila ll, posbilb zz

WHERE 
    ll.bill_no = zz.receive_ID 
    AND 
    zz.stkcode >= '0' 
    AND 
    zz.stkcode <= 'zz' 
    AND 
    date_format(ll.billdate,"yyyy") = 2016

group by zz.StkCode, ll.bill_date
union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-01-31') 
union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-02-01') 
union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-03-31')
union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-04-30') 
union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-05-31') 
union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-06-30')
union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-07-31') 
union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-08-31') 
union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-09-30')
union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-10-31') 
union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-11-30') 
union select 2, 0, concat(@yyyy,'-12-31') 
) as bb

left join icstk kk on bb.stockcode = kk.stockcode

Group By 1, date_1

I have this query :
date_1    stkcode   Qty   stockcode    description
02/16     COKE      13    COKE         COKE123
03/16     COKE      112   COKE         COKE123
04/16     COKE      6     COKE         COKE123
06/16     COKE      5     COKE         COKE123
```

but i want something like:

```
date_1    stkcode   Qty   stockcode    description
01/16               0
02/16     COKE      13    COKE         COKE123
03/16     COKE      112   COKE         COKE123
04/16     COKE      6     COKE         COKE123
05/16               0
06/16     COKE      5     COKE         COKE123
07/16               0
08/16     COKE      5     COKE         COKE123
09/16               0
10/16               0
11/16     COKE      15    COKE         COKE123
12/16     COKE      25    COKE         COKE123
```

Comment: Hmm..looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474796/how-to-select-data-of-all-months-of-user-selected-year-even-its-empty/38476280?noredirect=1#comment64399944_38476280.

Comment: You should change your implicit joins to explicit joins. Regarding allowing the user to set the date you only have mysql tagged so user would need access to code and mysql which doesn't sound good - do you have some front end such as php?

Comment: I use VB with its window form.

Comment: Genarally it would be the job of the user facing front end to build a sql query, invoke it and present the results. To attract useful answers you should include appropriate tags and include a description of what you are trying to do with sample code of how you are trying to do it.

Comment: I am doing a report that let user to enter year and stock code. The report will show the monthly sales of an item from Jan to Dec of the selected year from user. The results must be all 12 months even if data not exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can add JAN to DEC month entry in tempTable and left join that table with your statement
```